# react-native-background-geolocation: postTemplate not working on iOS platform

Tags: react-native

I'm using this module to send user's coordinates to api based upon distanceFilter, on Android platform it is working fine but in iOS i'm in trouble. I'm facing the issue with the postTemplate. Here is given below configuration provided, please have a look and let me know what's the wrong with it.

Module Link: https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation

```
BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
    desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.HIGH_ACCURACY,
    stationaryRadius: 20,
    distanceFilter: 10,
    notificationTitle: 'location tracking enabled',
    notificationText: 'user location tracking enabled',
    startForeground: true,
    debug: true,
    startOnBoot: false,
    stopOnTerminate: true,
    locationProvider: BackgroundGeolocation.DISTANCE_FILTER_PROVIDER,
    stopOnStillActivity: true,
    interval: 5000,
    url: 'https://example.com/Activity/AddEmployeeCoordinates',
    httpHeaders: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    // customize post properties
    postTemplate: {
        "Latitude": "@latitude",
        "Longitude": "@longitude",
        "foo": "bar"
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi... Same Problem.. Did you find the solution though ???